# Use of .not() in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to implement .not() in a jQuery line.  I want each checkbox to bring up the countries from the OTHER region, ie if you click 'Europe' I want 'China' and 'Japan' to show. I want to change the jQuery code without making any change to the HLML.  I've tried

```
`$('.my' + (.not($(this))).attr("id")).slideToggle(200)`
```

but it doesn't work.  Can anyone help?  Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/h74rtvz8/

```
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" id="Europe" />Europe</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" id="Asia" />Asia</label>

<div class="mywrapper">
<label class="myEurope">
<input type="checkbox" value="Germany" />Germany</label>
<label class="myEurope">
<input type="checkbox" value="Austria" />Austria</label>
<label class="myAsia"><input type="checkbox" value="China" />China</label>
<label class="myAsia"><input type="checkbox" value="Japan" />Japan</label>
</div>



$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
$('.my' + $(this).attr("id")).slideToggle(200)
})



.mywrapper {
border: 1px solid blue;
height: 200px;
width: 300px;
border: 1px solid blue;
}

.myEurope {
display: none;
}

.myAsia {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: I don't know who has downgraded my question and accused me of lack of research effort, but I can assure everyone that several hours of research have been spent on this.  Being a newbie I may well be missing the obvious, or going down the wrong track, but there's definitely no lack of effort!

Comment: is radio buttons a option?

Comment: The code that you have tried shows incorrect way of using `.not()`. Its going to cause syntax error. Have you checked JQuery documentation @ http://api.jquery.com/not/ to know how to use `.not()`? Take a look at examples given in documentation, that should clarify how to use it and then try your code one more time. (btw, I've not downvoted your question :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relax. chill out. Don't mad because of this question has been downgraded.

Here's my example for you. Maybe this is what you

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
  // $('.my' + $(this).attr("id")).slideToggle(200);
  $('.mywrapper > label:not(.my' + $(this).attr("id")+")").slideToggle(200);
  // @
  // $('.mywrapper').find("label").not(".my" + $(this).attr("id")).slideToggle(200);
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/synz/w3rvm3ss/3/

Comment: Really? so I just misunderstood his question then
I thought he want the opposite. Click 'Europe' -> show China and Japan.
Because his working right now if click 'Europe' -> show the Germany and Austria

Comment: @synz, that's brilliant.  You understood the question perfectly. I know I'd have struggled for many more hours without this help.  I'll try and chill (!), I just thought that the downgrade might put off the experts from having a go at the question.